# SQL to check if exists with condition or not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following scenario:

I want to `select a mission from a table(missions) for a user (userID=?)`, or I will select all missions  if user is not assigned to any mission.

This can be achieved in 2 queries:

```
   Select * from missions where userID = :ID
```

If (result is empty)

```
   Select * from missions
```

I want these 2 SQL in one SQL if possible any Idea

I other words. User can eather select  messions he assigned to by admin or he can work with all messions.

Comment: Sounds like you need two queries. There's no "but if empty" in SQL. You can `UNION` but that will *always* run, not conditionally. There may be a way to do this with a `CASE` and a bunch of gnarly sub-selects, but I'd stay away from that. It won't be faster.

Comment: The answer by Tim should work, but, it seems like a strange design to me - on the second case where userID != :ID then the users would get all the missions assigned to ANY user, not just all the missions without a set id

Answer (score 2):

You may try:

```
SELECT *
FROM missions
WHERE
    userID = :ID OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM missions WHERE userID = :ID);
```

Should one or more records exist with `userID = :ID`, the first condition would be true for those records, and the exists condition would also be false, and therefore ignored.  Should *no* records exist with `userID = :ID`, then the first condition would always be false, and therefore ignored, while the second condition would always be true, thereby returning the entire table.